# How to download/install alethzero ethereum client download windows 10?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, alethzero

I am new to Ethereum and when  i see some videos i found they are using alethzero ethereum client installed and running contracts.

I am unable to find from where can i download alethzero ethereum client
How can i install and run alethzero ethereum client ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Alethzero (and AlethOne and AlethFive) are [discontinued](https://github.com/ethereum/alethzero):

> Our focus is now on HTML5-based GUI solutions such as [remix](https://github.com/ethereum/remix), which can
>   be used within browser-solidity, Mist, Atom, Visual Studio Code, and
>   other IDE integrations, rather than building standalone C++ GUI
>   applications.